# Open Slack thread pane via API

Tags: slack-api

Every unthreaded message in Slack has a button to "Reply in thread" which opens the thread pane when the message itself isn't yet a thread. Can this same behavior be accomplished with the Slack API? The only route I can see is to post a threaded message then navigate to that message via permalink which would be pretty clunky.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done in this way:**

Let's assume the user is clicking (action) on a VIEW button that holds the url. See below example for a better understanding. You need to ack() the action to the slack in your code.

[Image of view button in message surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42xwj.png)

and it's block,

```
{
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "This is message surface"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "View"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "action_id": "view_action_id",
                "url": "https://domain.slack.com/archives/C05E***BCG/p1701250903039929?thread_ts=1701250903.039929"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

You need to just ack the action to the slack in your code. (Python)

```
@app.action("view_action_id")
def handle_some_action(ack, body, logger):
    ack()
```

`https://domain.slack.com/archives/C05E***BCG/p1701250903039929` will take you to the message in main pane.

`https://domain.slack.com/archives/C05E***BCG/p1701250903039929?thread_ts=1701250903.039929`, Adding `thread_ts` in thread will take to the message in `Reply in thread` pane. Remember, Both p and thread_ts timestamp has to be same for your case. And C05E***BCG is your channel ID.